# Visual Studio ignore try catch - debug only

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I think error handling is a good idea.  :)  When debugging it can get in the way - especially with nice user friendly messages.  In VB6 I could just check a box for the compiler to ignore my error handling.  I **[found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893277/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-visual-studio-to-ignore-try-catch-in-debug-mode)** the dialog that allows me to do something similar in VS, but it's about 10,000 check boxes instead of one - which is too many to change every time I want a production compilation.

Is there a way to set VS up so when I am in debugging mode I get one set of conditions and when I am in production I get another?  ...or is there just another method to handling errors and debugging more efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893277/is-there-a-better-way-to-get-visual-studio-to-ignore-try-catch-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 3):

Try the Debug Menu and look at Exceptions. You can set it to automatically break when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

In code, I'd probably just do something like:

```
#if !DEBUG
    try {
#endif
        DoSomething();
#if !DEBUG
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogEx(ex);
        throw new FriendlyException(ex);
    }
#endif
```

Or. more generally and with less `#if`:

```
#if DEBUG
   public const bool DEBUG = true;
#else
   public const bool DEBUG = false;
#endif

try {
   DoSomething();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   if (DEBUG) throw;
   LogEx(ex);
   throw new FriendlyException(ex);
}
```

Or, general purpose (like the Exception Handling library from P&P):

```
bool HandleException(Exception ex) {
    return !DEBUG;
}
```

But, if your real problem is just the Visual Studio GUI - [just use a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

You can add this attribute to your methods:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

You can also use #if #endif statements if you wish.

Comment: That's going to make for *very* ugly code; there are better ways to handle this in VS.Net.

Comment: +1 I agree that that the #if makes ugly code, the attribute method I don't think it does, however it is limiting.